# Production of Nitrogen Vacancy Centers

Tags: condensed-matter, atmospheric-science, biophysics

A Nitrogen Vacancy Center is a diamond defect in which a carbon atom is replaced by a Nitrogen and the adjacent carbon atom is replaced by a "vacancy", hence the term Nitrogen Vacancy (NV). NVs have many applications to magnetometry and medicine, but I have two, perhaps unconventional, questions about NVs:

- Can NVs emerge from a biological source? In other words, would it be possible for an organism to release NVs in the process of excretion or respiration or consume NVs for metabolic purposes? As it is a carbon and nitrogen based structure, I suspect it may be possible, as CHON (Carbon, Hydrogen, Oxygen, Nitrogen) are the four most common elements in living organisms. Furthermore, recent studies have demonstrated that [diamonds found in oceanic rocks have been recycled from organic carbon deep within the Earth's mantle](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-96286-8).
- Can NVs be found or produced in the atmosphere or near the ocean floor where there's high pressure?

I believe the questions are related to PSE, as they are bio/geophysical in nature, but please let me know if you think otherwise. Any response is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What biographical sources are made of diamond?

Comment: @JonCuster Just a few months ago, a study published in Nature documented that [oceanic diamonds have an organic origin](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-021-96286-8). Perhaps I should link that in my main question.

Comment: The article you reference talks about the origin of diamonds with different carbon isotopes. Some originate from ancient continents that are subducted into the Earth's interior. These melt at depths of 100 - 300 km. Carbon in those continents has isotope ratios like that from organic life (possibly because they are from ancient organisms?) These can be carried to the surface by mantle plumes, along with other kinds of diamonds with different isotope ratios from much deeper. None of these are formed by living organisms. They form at immense pressure and temperature where nothing can live.

Comment: Can someone explain why there's a downvote? I can improve my question if necessary, but that downvote is not constructive at all.

Comment: @mmesser314 Thanks for the feedback. However, to my understanding, extremophiles such as tardigrades can indeed survive at such deep pressures and extreme temperatures. Would such isotopes thus be a sign of once-existing organisms? Should I modify my question as such?

Comment: Extremophiles can survive in some surprising places, such as buried in porous rock at 1 km depth, or near hydrothermal vents on the sea floor. But rock melts at depths of 100 km. Nothing survives in lava.

Comment: @mmesser314 Do my questions have any validity, then? Is it possible to modify it to make it better?

Comment: Diamonds are formed deep in the Earth. Biology, atmosphere, and sea floor are not involved. Diamonds are found on the surface where volcanoes have carried them up from the depths. Here is a video that explains how volcanoes work. [Why China's Largest Volcano Is So Unusual](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3C2HVOB-g5s). It isn't directly related to diamonds, but I found it interesting.

Comment: @mmesser314 Thank you for the link. So just to confirm, even though the organisms participate in the organic carbon cycle, it's not possible for them to release or consume carbon lattices (i.e., diamonds)

Comment: I do not know. Life does not participate in the formation of diamonds. But diamonds are carbon. I don't know if anything could consume diamonds. Diamonds are extremely rare, so nothing would have evolved to feed on them. But I suppose something might be able to feed on it, given the chance.

Comment: @mmesser314 My motivation for asking this question is I'm wondering whether carbon lattices or even imperfections in them (i.e., NVs) could be a viable biosignature on exoplanets. But, then again, I'm simply speculating here and I'm open to any feedback or discussion